# Inserting values into a recursive table?

Tags: mysql, recursion

Well, I have another problem with the recursive table.

This is the table definition:

```
create table seguridad (
    cod_emple int(6) ZEROFILL NOT NULL,
    cod_jefe int(6) ZEROFILL DEFAULT NULL,
    TIP int(5) NOT NULL,
    division_seguridad varchar(40) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (cod_emple),
    INDEX (cod_jefe),
    FOREIGN KEY (cod_jefe) REFERENCES seguridad (cod_emple) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (cod_emple) REFERENCES empleados (cod_emple) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=INNODB;
```

But when I try to insert this:

```
insert into seguridad values (002237, 2213, 28465, 'VIGILANTE');
```

or

```
insert into empleados values (002889, NULL, 26675, 'GUARDIA CIVIL');
```

I get this error on the first:

```
#1452. Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`prision_arenales`.`seguridad`, CONSTRAINT `seguridad_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`cod_jefe`) REFERENCES `seguridad` (`cod_emple`) ON UPDATE CASCADE)
```

And this on the second:

```
#1136. Column count doesn't match value count at row 1
```

What I'm doing wrong? I have done the same thing from https://planet.mysql.com/entry/?id=599259

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first means that `seguridad (cod_emple)` doesnt have the value `002237` contained in it

Th second means that `empleados` does not have 5 columns